# Have vixie-cron log to file

Tags: linux, cron, system, administration

I am trying to get vixie-cron to send any output to a log file rather than as an email to root(or user).  Is there are configuration way to do this rather than redirecting the stderr and stdout file streams within the command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not that I know of.

However there are other `cron` (`cronie` has -s for logging output to `syslog`).

Comment: I have not found anything to dispute this assertion so I am accepting it as confirmation of what I found on the web.  Thanks for answering.